# When writing test code in JavaScript, I wonder why it "requires" as follows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-router-dom

```js
import React from 'react';
// or
const React = require('react');

describe('...', () => ...);
```

I am studying to write good test code.
The code below is the test code of react-dom, why write it as below?
Shouldn't it be written like the code above?

```js
'use strict';

let React;
let ReactDOM;
let ReactDOMServer;
let ReactTestUtils;

describe('ReactDOM', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    React = require('react');
    ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
    ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
    ReactTestUtils = require('react-dom/test-utils');
  });

  it('allows a DOM element to be used with a string', () => {
    const element = React.createElement('div', {className: 'foo'});
    const node = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(element);
    expect(node.tagName).toBe('DIV');
  });
```

Comment: "The code below is the test code of react-dom" Can you link to this in your question?

Comment: Sure, here link!
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/__tests__/ReactDOM-test.js

Answer (score 1):

If you click on Blame button, you should see the history of that code

[image]

That code was written like 3 years ago where ES Module (import/export syntax) is not standardized yet, and CommonJS (require syntax) is pretty popular at that time. There are other factor like transpiler (Babel), bundler as well.

But for today code, you should go for ES Module style:

```
 import React from 'react';
```

Comment: Could you please explain why we need to do "require" in "beforeEach"?
Is this also cjs style?